# Convert to IEnumerable<dynamic>?

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, extension-methods, ienumerable

I wrote this extension method :

```
public static class A
{
 public static IEnumerable<dynamic> AsDynamic<T>(this IEnumerable<T> f)
    {
        foreach (var element in f)
        {
                yield return (dynamic) element;
        }   
    }
}
```

And tested it :

```
List<int> l   = new List<int>(){1,2,3};
Console.WriteLine ( l.AsDynamic().GetType());
```

However the output is : `typeof (IEnumerable<Object>)`

- Why it is not `typeof (IEnumerable<dynamic>)`  ?
- How can I make it to be like it ?

Comment: ["In most cases, it functions like it has type object."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx)

Comment: There is no `dynamic` type at runtime, they are just typed as object and the method binding information is output at each call site involving a dynamic variable.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think that you have a misunderstanding of what `dynamic` means. Essentially, when you tell the compiler that an object's type is `dynamic`, you "promise" that the object **at runtime** will support whatever methods or properties that you invoke, in exchange for the compiler not complaining **at compile time**. You also promise that you will face the consequences if you break your promise.

When you say that an object is `dynamic`, the compiler cannot make assumptions about the type, so it uses `object`, knowing that anything can be stored as `object`. When you make an `IEnumerable<dynamic>`, it becomes `IEnumerable<object>`, with one significant difference: you can call any method on its elements, and the compiler will not say a word:

```
IEnumerable<SomeType> original = ...
foreach (dynamic x in original.AsDynamic()) { // Using your method
    Console.WriteLine(x.SomeUnsupportedMethod()); // The compiler is silent!
}
```

Since `original.AsDynamic()` gives a sequence of `dynamic` objects, the compiler does not complain about your call to `SomeUnsupportedMethod`. If the method is indeed not supported at runtime, the program will crash; if the method is actually supported by elements of `SomeType`, there would be no crash, and the method will be invoked.

That's all the `dynamic` will do for you; statically, the "placeholder" will remain `object`, and `typeof` will tell you as much. But the exact capabilities of the object (its methods and properties) will not be examined until runtime.

Comment: As I understand from discussions in comments to another answer, writing `typeof(IEnumerable<dynamic>)` is actually legal (but not useful!) in C#, but it creates the same runtime type as `typeof(IEnumerable<Object>)`. However, `typeof(dynamic)` is not allowed as a synonym for `typeof(object)`. By the way, `GetType()` will never return an interface type, of course, so the Original Poster was not being precise.

Comment: @RoyiNamir I'm not sure I understand your screen shot (I'm not familiar with LINQPad). The two lines have different typography. They are not the output of the two `WriteLine` method calls. The `GetType()` returns a `RuntimeType` object, in the first `WriteLine` the `ToString()` method is called on it. The type will be a generated type (class with a weird name with `<`, `>`, and `__` characters in it) because you have an iterator block (`yield return`). Try this: `if (l.AsDynamic().GetType() == typeof(IEnumerable<Object>)) throw new Exception("Jeppe was wrong!");`

Answer (score 1):

Because `dynamic` is not a type

```
Console.WriteLine(typeof(dynamic)); // error
```

dynamic just resolves the actual type at runtime

Comment: MSDN refers to "type" as well: [Visual C# 2010 introduces a new type, dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx)

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ - Trying to use `typeof(dynamic)` results in a compile error, "The typeof operator cannot be used on the dynamic type."

Comment: @Lee `dynamic` is a type that is not known at run time..dynamic and object are similar except dynamic lets you do things which cant be done at compile time

Comment: @Lee Is it legal to say `typeof(List<dynamic>)`? Of course, if you say `dynamic d1 = 123; d1.GetType();` you expect `System.Int32`, where as `dynamic d2 = new List<dynamic>(); d2.GetType();` probably returns ``List`1[System.Object]``?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen - Yes, `typeof(List<dynamic>)` is allowed, and you are correct that it is the same as `typeof(List<object>)` at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

By design, *runtime* bindings behave as **similarly** as possible to *static* binding.

So the runtime type would be`typeof (IEnumerable<Object>)`

The static type would be `typeof (IEnumerable<dynamic>)`

Also

The runtime treats this true conceptually

```
typeof(object)==typeof(dynamic)
```

So,

A dynamic type is like object except it lets you use in ways that aren't known at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Linq Extension method [Cast()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx). But I'm not sure it will work with dynamic.