# Should I create a dedicated class for this anonymous type?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code in one of my functions

```
goodsQuery = db.Goods.Select(g => new { g.name, g.description, g.image, g.price });
```

If it has been defined inside the method I would have used the *var* type.
But what type I have to use when the variable defines as class field?

Of course `IEnumerable<Goods>` doesn't go well.
Tryed to use `IEnumerable<object>` but result is the same.

Should I create a new class for this?

Comment: _"Should I create a new class for this?"_ Yes!

Comment: Tryed to use IEnumerable<dynamic>. And it works great. Are there any hidden dangers?

Comment: Yes, there is no dynamic type at runtime. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14111221/284240 Use `dynamic` only if you must. In most cases you should use classes.

Comment: @Novikoff `dynamic` will perform much more poorly, as you'll be compiling code at runtime, it will be much harder to maintain as neither you nor future developers will have an effective way of knowing what the actual properties of the items are when using that field, they'll constantly need to be looking up the query to see what the fields are, and they violate standard naming conventions (properties should start with an upper case letter) which is likely to cause typos which won't be caught at compile time, only runtime, and the loss of Intellisense will cost you more time than you'll save.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using an [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx). This can only exist within the scope of a function. If you want the results to be usable in a property, you'll need to create a real class for this.

> You cannot declare a field, a property, an event, or the return type
>   of a method as having an anonymous type. Similarly, you cannot declare
>   a formal parameter of a method, property, constructor, or indexer as
>   having an anonymous type. To pass an anonymous type, or a collection
>   that contains anonymous types, as an argument to a method, you can
>   declare the parameter as type object. However, doing this defeats the
>   purpose of strong typing. If you must store query results or pass them
>   outside the method boundary, consider using an ordinary named struct
>   or class instead of an anonymous type.

Answer (score 1):

if using C# 4 you can also use `dynamic` if creating a class isn't feasible...

But it seems class `Good` (strange name) is a better option here.